# How to open url as "chrome-extension" in web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have one web page and one chrome extension, how can I open url like this chrome-extension://chrome-id/page.html. Here is my code:

```
 $(document).on('click', '#btnOpenChromeExtension', function () {
    window.open("chrome-extension://chrome-id/webpage.html", "_blank");
 });
```

But when click, it open new tab in blank page with url is: about:blank. How can I open link is chrome-extension ?

Comment: Does it work (or do something else) when you leave out the second parameter? From w3schools: _blank - URL is loaded into a new window. This is default

so there's no need to specify it. Still a strange situation... Does the URL you supply lead to the extension when you paste it into the address bar manually?

Comment: @NilsO It work normaly with url contains "http", but it seem to be not work with url contains "chrome-extension"

Answer (score 6):

This is restricted due to the extension policies. You need to add to the extension's manifest.json file the following:

```
{
    ...
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "page/mypage.html"
    ],
    ...
}
```

Of course, this must be your extension. This is the only way I know to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnOpenChromeExtension', function () {
      window.location.href = "chrome-extension://chrome-id/webpage.html";
      //        OR       
      window.location.replace("chrome-extension://chrome-id/webpage.html");
});
```

Comment: Nope. You can't normally open `chrome-extension://` or `chrome://` pages due to security restrictions, and this will not work.

Comment: @xan i remember you answered recently this could be done with tabs instead of window.open

Comment: @ZigMandel Correct. "Normally" here means "with methods available to webpages".

Comment: @sorryxi wasnt commenting on that but on the fact that the tabs thing isn't mentioned anywhere and seems to be better than the current 2 answers.